# IIS express not serving ES6 javascript modules

Tags: asp.net, iis, es6-modules

I started using ES6 javascript modules in my ASP.NET MVC application but IIS express is refusing to serve javascript file of type *module* in *script* tag. I'm getting **401 Unauthorized**.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/index.js" type="module"></script>
```

When i remove `type="module"` from `script` tag then it works fine.

Are request filters involved? Can you please help me set them right?

Comment: This is happening to me now as well. Did you every find the solution?

Comment: Not really. I resolved it by compiling all js files in one using node.js module system (instead of ES6 modules) and [browserify](http://browserify.org/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into the same issue in a pretty bare-bones Apache setup for personal use. I was pretty dumbfounded until I came across [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-es6-modules/).

Check out the small section titled "Server Considerations", which mentions the use of `crossorigin="use-credentials"` in the `<script>` tag. It sounded only vaguely relevant since I'm working exclusively on a local origin, but I had nothing else to go on so tried it on a whim and it worked.

I can't pretend to understand why, or speak to any unintended consequences, so I would suggest diving into those aspects before pasting this into deployment.

Comment: Another article with relevant info: [link](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/). See the link to [whatwg issue #2557](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/2557), which nods to the questionable use of cross-origin designation for same-origin behavior and recommends using `crossorigin="anonymous"` instead.

Comment: For me, just adding the `crossorigin` attribute (without a value) did the trick.